# How to send custom drop down option on shipping method step

Tags: magento-1.9, email, custom

I have just added a custom drop down option at the payment method section for users to select. Once the payment success, this extra custom option will be sent to the store's email along with all the other `shipping/billing/etc` information.

Which file do I edit now to allow this added custom field to be sent along with all the other fields? I just don't know how this all handled in the Magento system at the moment.

The code I just added in shipping_method.phtml:

```
<div class="occassion">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('Special Occassion?'); ?></h4>
        <select>
            <option value="" selected>None</option>
            <option value="birthday">Birthday</option>
            <option value="valentines">Valentine's Day</option>
            <option value="holidays">Holidays</option>
            <option value="anniversary">Anniversary</option>
            <option value="graduation">Graduation</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **observer(after order success [checkout_onepage_controller_success_action])** to track order and get the order payment status if payment status is success mail to user/admin with that extra custom option value.

There are below some events to capture order detail:

- checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
- sales_order_payment_capture
- sales_order_invoice_pay

You can use one of above observer events.

Note: To learn observer in magento read link http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-magento-events-customer-first-order/